# How to get all the posts from rss feed rather than the latest posts?

Tags: rss, feed

Rss seems only have the latest n posts, I just wonder is there anyway to get all the posts including the history post.  Thanks

Jeff Zhang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't generally possible since a RSS reader only shows what is currently in the feed. You can only pull as much as is published at that time. Finding the dataset which backs the RSS feed items and downloading directly from there is something else entirely though and is sometimes possible.

Answer (score 0):

using c# you can do it but it will return the Json not in Rss format.
you have to do like

```
   string AccessToken="Your Access Token e.g KIMJSLIFJEILMFSLJFSDIIIIFLDFJSLFJLSFSLFJSLJF";
   var client= new facebookclient(AccessToken);
   dynamic allFeeds=client.Get("me/feed");//OR  "me/feeds


        foreach (var uniquefeed in (JsonArray)allFeeds["data"])
        {
            string feedids = (string)(((JsonObject)uniquefeed )["id"]);
            //Write more stuff here what you want.
        }
```