# Get all RSS feed entries with Rome Library

Tags: java, rss, rome

i am using Rome library for Java to parse some RSS.
By default it takes 25 entries.

Tell me please, how to get next 25 entries?

My test code is:

```
public static SyndFeed getSyndFeedForUrl(String url) throws Exception {

    SyndFeed feed = null;
    InputStream is = null;

    try {

        URLConnection openConnection = new URL(url).openConnection();
        is = new URL(url).openConnection().getInputStream();
        if("gzip".equals(openConnection.getContentEncoding())){
            is = new GZIPInputStream(is);
        }
        InputSource source = new InputSource(is);
        SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
        feed = input.build(source);

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if( is != null) is.close();
    }

    return feed;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        SyndFeed feed;
        try {
            feed = getSyndFeedForUrl("http://example.com/rss");
            List res = feed.getEntries();
            for(Object o : res) {
                System.out.println(((SyndEntryImpl) o).getDescription().getValue());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `feed.getEntries()`, Rome library returns all entries that are available in `http://example.com/rss`. It is not possible to get more than there are in the xml document (unless the entries have been cached in some service like Feedly).

See

- [How to get all the posts from rss feed rather than the latest posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962017/how-to-get-all-the-posts-from-rss-feed-rather-than-the-latest-posts)
- [How to get more feeds from RSS url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110170/how-to-get-more-feeds-from-rss-url?rq=1)
- [How Do I Fetch All Old Items on an RSS Feed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576552/how-do-i-fetch-all-old-items-on-an-rss-feed?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Unfortunately, i cannot rate your answer (not enough reputation)