# How to read previous rss feed (next feed)) in java?

Tags: java, rss, feed, rss-reader, rome

Right now I can read the current RSS feed (10 items) using `rome library` in java. I want to read the previous articles from the RSS feed. Thank you for any suggestions. Here is my sample code for reading the RSS feed.

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(blogURL);
    XmlReader reader = new XmlReader(url);
    SyndFeed feed = new SyndFeedInput().build(reader);
    List<Article> list = new ArrayList<Article>();

    for (Iterator<?> i = feed.getEntries().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        SyndEntry entry = (SyndEntry) i.next();
        Article article = BeansHelper.getInstance().createArticleBean(entry);
        article.setWebsiteURl(link);
        list.add(article);
    }   
} catch(MalformedURLException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Get all RSS feed entries with Rome Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33764251/get-all-rss-feed-entries-with-rome-library/33773607#33773607)

`feed.getEntries()` returns all articles that are available.